# Request proof for proof for $x,y$ in the same orbit : if $y=gx,$ then $\mathrm{Stab}(y)=g\mathrm{Stab}(x)g^{-1}.$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, coloring

If $y,x$ lie in the same orbit, wrt action by the elements of the group $G,$ then need proof for : if $y=gx,$ then $\mathrm{Stab}(y)=g\mathrm{Stab}(x)g^{-1}.$

For example, have the [below table](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4572585/424260) (*set members  with colorings: $0000, 1111$ not shown, due to forming singleton orbits*)
for the action of the group of rotations of a tetrahedron, on the set $X$ of the $2$-colorings of the four vertices of the same.
Have the set $X$ size as $=2^4=16.$

Also, if take
$x=1000, g= (234), y=(0100).$
Hence, $0010= (234)1000.$
And, $\mathrm{Stab}(1000)=\{e, (123), (132)\},$
$\mathrm{Stab}(0010)=\{e, (143), (134)\},$
$(234)(\{e, (123), (132)\})(432)$
$(234)(\{(432), (412),(13)(24)\}).$

Then, should get $\{e, (143), (134)\}=(234)\{e, (123), (132)\}(432).$
Applying composition of permutations, on the rhs, from right to left, get:
$(234)\{e, (123), (132)\}(432)$
$=(234)\{(432),(124), (13)(24)\} =\{e, (134), (143)\}$

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\text{S. No.} & e & (234) & (432) & (123) & (132) & (134) & (143)& (124) & (142) & (12)(34) & (13)(24)& (14)(23) & \mathcal {O}\\ \hline
1& 0001 & 0001 = 1 & 0001=1 & 0010=2 & 0100 =4& 0100 =4& 1000 = 8& 0010= 2 & 1000 = 4& 0010=2 & 0100=4 & 1000=8 & \{1,2,4,8\}=\mathcal O_1 \\
2 & 0010 & 0100=4 & 1000 =8& 0100=4 & 0001=1 & 0010 =2& 0010 =2& 1000=8 & 0001=1 & 0001 =1& 1000 =8& 0100=4 & \{1,2,4,8\}=\mathcal O_1 \\
3 & 0011 & 0101=5 & 1001=9 & 0110=6 & 0101=5 & 0110 =6& 1010=10 & 1010=10 & 1001=9 & 0011 =3& 1100=12 & 1010= 10 &\{3,5,6,9,10,12\}=\mathcal O_2 \\
4 & 0100 & 1000=8 & 0010=2 & 0001=1 & 0010=2 & 1000=8 & 0001=1 & 0100=4 & 0100=4 & 1000=8 & 0001=1 & 0010= 2 &\{1,2,4,8\}=\mathcal O_1 \\
5 & 0101 & 1001=9 & 0011=3 & 0011=3 & 0110=6 & 1100 & 1001=9 & 0110=6 & 1100=12 & 1010=10 & 0101=5 & 1010=10 & \{3,5,6, 9, 10, 12\}=\mathcal O_2 \\
6 & 0110 & 1100 =12& 1010=10 & 0101=5 &  0011=3 & 1010=10 & 0011=3 & 1100=12 & 0101=5 & 1001=9 &1001=9 & 0110=6 & \{3,5,6,9,10,12\} =\mathcal O_2 \\
7 & 0111 & 1101=13 & 1011=11 &  0111=7 &  0111=7 & 1110=14 & 1011=11 & 1110=14 & 1101=13 & 1011=11 &1101=13 & 1110=14&\{7, 11,13,14\}=\mathcal O_3 \\ 
8 & 1000 & 0010=2 & 0100=4 &  1000=8 & 1000=8 & 0001=1 & 0100=4 & 0001=1 & 0010=2 & 0100 =4& 0010=2 & 0001=2&\{1,2,4,8\}=\mathcal O_1 \\
9 & 1001 & 0011=3 &  0101=5 & 1010=6 & 1100=12 & 0101=5 & 1100=12 & 0011=3 & 1010=10 & 0110=6 & 0110 = 6& 1001=9&\{3,5,6,9,10,12\}=\mathcal O_2 \\
10 & 1010 & 0110=6 & 1100=12 & 1100=12 & 1001=9 & 0011=3 & 0110 =6& 1001=9 & 0011=3 & 0101=5 &1010=10 & 0101=5&\{3,5,6,9,10,12\}=\mathcal O_2 \\
11 & 1011 & 0111=7 & 1101=13 & 1110=14 & 1101=13 & 0111=7 & 1110=14 & 1011=11 & 1011=11 & 0111=7 & 1110=14 & 1101=13&\{7,11,13,14\}=\mathcal O_3 \\
12 & 1100 & 1010 =10& 0110=6 & 1001=9& 1010=10 & 1001=9 & 0101=5 & 0101=5 & 0110=6 & 1100=12 & 0011=3 & 0011=3&\{3,5,6,9,10,12\}=\mathcal O_2 \\
13 & 1101 & 1011=11 & 0111=7 & 1011=11& 1110 =14&1101=13 & 1101 =13& 0111=7 & 1110 =14& 1110=14 & 0111 =7& 1011=11&\{7,11,13,14\}=\mathcal O_3 \\
14 & 1110 & 1110 =14& 1110=14 & 1101=13 & 1011=11 & 1011 =11& 0111=7 & 1101 =13& 0111=7 & 1101=13 & 1011=11 & 0111 =7&\{7,11,13,14\}=\mathcal O_3 \\
\end{array}

Comment: Maybe this will help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4560374/conjugate-stabilisers-with-group-actions/4560442#4560442

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Thanks, and that seems the correct way to frame the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $h\in stab(gx) $,

$$\begin{align}
hgx=gx &\implies g^{-1}hgx=x \\
&\implies g^{-1}hg \in stab(x) \\
&\implies h\in g Stab(x) g^{-1}
\end{align}$$

So $$Stab(y) \subset gStab(x) g^{-1}$$ In the same way, you can prove the reverse inclusion by noting that it is equivalent to $$Stab(x) \subset g^{-1}Stab(y)g $$

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the set-builder notation (namely without the double inclusion):
\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{Stab}(y) &= \{g'\in G\mid g'y=y\} \\
&= \{g'\in G\mid g'gx=gx\} \\
&= \{g'\in G\mid g^{-1}g'gx=x\} \\
\tag1
\end{alignat}
Now, call $g'':=g^{-1}g'g$; then, $g':=gg''g^{-1}$, which plugged into $(1)$ yields:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{Stab}(y) &= \{gg''g^{-1}\in G\mid g''x=x\} \\
&= g\{g''\in G\mid g''x=x\}g^{-1} \\
&= g\operatorname{Stab}(x)g^{-1} \\
\tag2
\end{alignat}